# How to add an existing user to a ManyToManyField in a model object via form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to figure out how to populate a drop-down selection form with a list of Users within the database. When the form is submitted I want the selected user to be added to a Task model objects ManyToMany users field. However the logic of doing so is confusing me. How do I populate a form with a list of model objects and how do I catch what object was submitted in the views.py file?

Answer (score 0):

**models.py**

```
class Task(models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('app.views',
    url(r'^task/(?P<task_id>\d+)/$', 'task', name='task'),
    url(r'^task/(?P<task_id>\d+)/adduser/$', 'add_user', name='add_user'),
)
```

**views.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect, render

from app.models import Task

class AddUserForm(forms.Form):
    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())        

def task(request, task_id):
    task = get_object_or_404(Task, pk=task_id)
    return render(request, 'task_detail.html',
                  {'task': task, 'form': AddUserForm()}

def add_user(request, task_id):
    task = get_object_or_404(Task, pk=task_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            task.users.add(form.cleaned_data['user'])
    return redirect('task', task_id)
```

**task_detail.html**:

```
<form action="{% url 'add_user' task.id %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <h1>{{ task.name }}</h1>

    <ul>
    {% for u in task.users.all %}
        <li>{{ u }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    <p>Add another user</p>
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button>Add</button>

</form>
```